# Can I use the parameter of an intent in the inline editor for Dialogflow?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

When using Dialogflow, parameters are set, in short, the training data may look something like this:

- I want cheese pizza
- I want ham pizza
- Give me a meat feast instead

So on CHEESE, HAM and MEAT FEAST, you would store them in a parameter, maybe known as `$PizzaChoice`

In the response section of the intent I know I can say "You chose `$PizzaChoice`".

But can I do this in the inline editor too? 
This below DOES NOT work, but I imagine if it's possible, it'd be something like:

```
agent.add('You selected' + $PizzaChoice);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `dialogflow-fulfillment` library, and following their usual convention of the parameter to the intent handler being named `agent`, then you can get all the parameters in an object at `agent.parameters`.

So the line you're looking to write would be something like

```
agent.add( 'You selected '+agent.parameters['PizzaChoice'] );
```

or, if you want to use the ES6 backquote templates:

```
agent.add( `You selected ${agent.parameters['PizzaChoice']}` );
```

Comment: Thank you @Prisoner, using the second option worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I have just noticed when I write either one of your suggestions I get an information tab next to the line suggesting `"['PizzaChoice'] is better written in dot notation"`...Any idea what that means?

Comment: It just means that, in this case, you can write it as `agent.parameters.PizzaChoice`. I chose the notations I did because parameter names can include characters where dot notation isn't possible. For example, "pizza-choice" is a valid parameter name, but `agent.parameters.pizza-choice` is **not** valid, but `agent.parameters['pizza-choice']` **is**.